# How can I find a value in a nested array and then return that parent?

Tags: php, arrays, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm returning a nested array from the Google maps API. What I'm trying to do is find a certain type inside the array. I'm using `json_decode` to convert the result from JSON to PHP. 
Here's the response that's being returned:

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [address_components] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => 78210
                                [short_name] => 78210
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => postal_code
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => San Antonio
                                [short_name] => San Antonio
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => locality
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Bexar County
                                [short_name] => Bexar County
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Texas
                                [short_name] => TX
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => United States
                                [short_name] => US
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => country
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [formatted_address] => San Antonio, TX 78210, USA
                [geometry] => Array
                    (
                        [bounds] => Array
                            (
                                [northeast] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 29.418426
                                        [lng] => -98.422923
                                    )

                                [southwest] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 29.374093
                                        [lng] => -98.499778
                                    )

                            )

                        [location] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 29.3979578
                                [lng] => -98.4677851
                            )

                        [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                        [viewport] => Array
                            (
                                [northeast] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 29.418426
                                        [lng] => -98.422923
                                    )

                                [southwest] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 29.374093
                                        [lng] => -98.499778
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [place_id] => ChIJy9U5Yzj2XIYRRhV9xWIghyU
                [types] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => postal_code
                    )

            )

    )

[status] => OK
)
```

What I need to do is find a certain type and return that `long_name` or `short_name`. I hope that makes sense.

So basically if the type = political then return that entire array so I can have access to the long_name and short_name.

I tried using array_search, but I'm not getting any result.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first array where found:

```
foreach($array['results'][0]['address_components'] as $v) {
    if(is_array($v['types']) && in_array('political', $v['types'])) {
        $result = $v;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want multiple then use `$result[] = $v;` and remove the `break`.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting an error that parameter 2 should be an array. For this line `if(in_array('political', $v['types'])) {`

Comment: Then your array is not as you posted in the question. Edited.

Comment: I've added the full response from the Google API. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You're missing `['results'][0]['address_components']`

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much! I truly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `array_map` function

```
$arr = array(
  0 => array(
     'long_name'  => 'Bexar County',
     'short_name' => 'Bexar County',
     'types' => array(
        0 => 'administrative_area_level_2',
        1 => 'political'
     )
   )   
);

$findType = 'political';
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($findType){
      if(in_array($findType, $v['types'])) 
        return $v;
}, $arr);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [long_name] => Bexar County
        [short_name] => Bexar County
        [types] => Array
            (
                [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                [1] => political
            )
    )
 )
```

Comment: Hi. I was also getting an error from this code. The line if(in_array($findType, $v['types']))  is saying in_array should be an array. But it's a string as it's `$findType`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Lz430 please share your full array

Comment: I added the full response to the question code above. You can actually see the response here: https://endeavorsdev1.wpengine.com/all-locations/  Just type in zip code 78210